# Multiple jquery toggles

Tags: jquery, toggle

Im trying to build a website that displays only one page to the public and with the help of jquery and ajax I plan to get all the hidden pages' content inside that very page. Like flash websites.
Now, being a newbie in this domain, I'm encountering some problems related to jquery toggeling. The `toggle()` function slides up and down every hidden page I need to display in the main page, but I do not know how to correctly close the others while one is being opened and make them 100% dinamic and pleasant to the eye.

In order to understand better what I'm saying, please follow [this link](http://www.mediaheart.ro/x/) and `click` on the `Marlon Brando`'s face, then `click` on the red text `formular online` and then click again on `Marlon Brando`'s face. *By doing this, you'll understand my problem exactly!*

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is something like this:

1. Give your content regions a common ancestor/parent, such as `<div id="regions"><div marlon /> <div formular /> ...`.
2. Give each of your main region divs an `id` or `rel` tag that you can relate to.  Such as `region-brando`
3. Give each link that expands a region a specific class (e.g. `region-expander`) and either make the `href` the id (e.g. `href="#region-brando"`) or set the rel tag (e.g. `rel="region-brando"`)
4. bind click events based on that class that does two things: 1) collapses every other currently expanded region inside the `regions` div; and 2) expands the newly selected region

So it'd look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/We9NT/

Comment: just a note, I'm not sure how complex this webpage is going to be, but making use of a clientside lib like backbone, angularjs, or something similiar might make managing your js a bit easier. My thought here is making use of a router. Also you may see this as overkill. just my 2 cents

Comment: +1 agreed.  It seems simple enough, but  as it gets complex, I think it's good to consider clientside libs as suggested by @Lucas.

Comment: @Lucas Well, I dont think it's gonna be that complex after all and I'll struggle to use jquery all the way. These are my first steps with the jQuery and I want to stay on this line. Thanks a lot for your care and advice.

Comment: @Eli Gassert: I found a workaround different than yours, but because it acts exactly like yours does ( :)) ) and you've spent your time trying to help me, I've accepted your answer. My way of saying thanks. ^^